# Js Prototype inheritance, is Object.create necessary?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.printName = function() {
    console.log(`my name is ${this.name}`)
}

function Dog(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name);
    this.speak = () => console.log('woof');
}

Dog.prototype = Animal.prototype // <=== **this line here**
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog


const leo = new Dog('leo')
leo.speak()
leo.printName()
```

Is there any difference between `Dog.prototype = Animal.prototype` AND `Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)` or they are both same?

Comment: Yes, very big differences. `Dog.prototype = Animal.prototype` will set the Dog prototype to the same object as Animal.prototype so if you add "bark" to Dog.prototype, all animals will bark thereafter. The proper prototype chain is where Dog instances inherit from Dog.prototype, which in turn inherits from Animal.prototype and for that you need `Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)`

Comment: @mplungjan yes makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can use more explicit `Object.setPrototypeOf()` to control prototype inheritance.
In that case you can add any methods to the Dog's prototype independently (even before inheritance).
So there's no need to rewrite the Dog's prototype.
Also you don't need to assign the Dog's constructor in that case, since it's kept intact.

```js
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.printName = function() {
    console.log(`my name is ${this.name}`)
}

function Dog(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name);
}

Dog.prototype.speak = () => console.log('woof');

Object.setPrototypeOf(Dog.prototype, Animal.prototype); 
// Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog - you don't need this, it's kept intact

const leo = new Dog('leo')
leo.speak()
leo.printName()
```